# How do I compile peercoin to generate windows binaries?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, compilation

I have been trying to compile peercoin (https://github.com/ppcoin/ppcoin) for windows and have failed so far.

The Linux one compiles on Ubuntu perfectly and most forums suggest using the compiler on Linux to generate windows binaries. I have never heard or using linux compiler to generate windows binaries.

So the question is : How do I compile the peercoin source for generating windows binaries?

Thanks

Edit: I tried the ming libraries as mentioned in the makefile but there are multiple compile time errors including non-descript errors like "unable to find matching '" etc.

Bounty for step by step explanation for generating the windows binaries (on Unix or Windows)

Comment: Have installed all the dependency packages mentioned in the [windows compilation readme](https://github.com/ppcoin/ppcoin/blob/master/doc/build-msw.txt)?
When you do, [this](http://www.blogcompiler.com/2010/07/11/compile-for-windows-on-linux/) is a very helpfull step by step tutorial on cross-compilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. The problem is that paths for mingw cannot end in "\" apparently. So my paths "c:\mingw-32" is perfectly fine but "c:\mingw-32\" throws an unable to find matching quotes error.